# Azure databricks connect to on-prem databases through ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

Is possible to connect an Azure Databricks notebook with Azure Data Factory linkedservices (connections to on prem DBs)?

On ADF, I have connections to on prem gateways through linked services to connect to local DBs. I need to connect my Databricks notebook with that linked services on ADF. It is possible?

Regards.

Comment: did you try anything now?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

You need to ensure your databricks resource is configured to be in the VNET which can talk to these databases.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject